# R - table() returns repeated factors

Tags: r, function

I'm using FiveThirtyEight's Star Wars survey.

On `$Anakin` I've assigned 0 (very unfavourably)  to 5 (very favourably) as categorical variables to the respondent's view of Anakin. "N/A" on the survey was assigned "". **(Did that step on MS Excel)**

`$Startrek` contains whether the respondent's seen Star Trek or not.

```
starwars <- read.csv2("starsurvey.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
as.factor(starwars$Anakin)
as.factor(starwars$Startrek)
tbl <- table(starwars$Anakin, starwars$Startrek)
```

The `table()` function returns this:

```
       No Yes
1   0  20  19
2   2  31  50
3   0  68  67
4   1 140 128
5   5 101 139
```

I'm wondering why the function returns 0, 2, 0, 1, 5 for the factors in `$Anakin`, since it contains:

```
starwars$Anakin
[1] 5    <NA> 4    5    2    5    4    3    4    5    <NA> <NA> 4    4           
[15] 4    2    3    5    5    5    4    3    3    2    5    <NA> 4    4   
[29] 1    1    3    5    2    <NA> <NA> 5    5    4    4    4    3    4   
[43] 4    4    4    4    <NA> 2    3    <NA> 4    4    5    4    4    <NA>
```

Comment: Those are the counts of people who gave a blank answer for Startrek

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I'm still new to R, so excuse me for it. Is there a way to choose your answer as the best one?

Comment: I've written up an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of table here is confusing because your factor levels (1 to 5) look like row numbers, and there are some blank (`""`) responses to the Startrek variable which makes it appear like the data is only under the No and Yes columns.

So, the data here is a 5 by 3 table, with the rows representing the score from `Anakin` (1 to 5) and the columns representing 3 types of response to `Startrek` (`""`, `No`, `Yes`).

Note that where there are NA's in `Anakin`, this data is ingored in the table. To count these too, use `addNA`:

```
table(addNA(starwars$Anakin), starwars$Startrek)
```